# Coordinate-free proof of $d (\omega \wedge \mu) = d \omega \wedge \mu + (-1)^k \omega \wedge d \mu$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\omega \in \Omega ^k (M)$ and $\mu \in \Omega ^l (M)$ and the exterior derivative defined by

$$ d \omega (X_1 , \dots , X_{k+1}) := \sum _{i = 1} ^{k + 1} (-1)^{i+1} X_i (\omega (X_1 , \dots , \hat{X}_i , \dots , X_{k+1})) \\
             + \sum_{i<j}^{k+1} (-1)^{i+j} \omega ([X_i , X_j] , X_1 , \dots , \hat{X}_i , \dots , \hat{X}_j , \dots , X_{k+1}). $$

How can I prove that

$$ d (\omega \wedge \mu) = d \omega \wedge \mu + (-1)^k \omega \wedge d \mu $$

without using a local representation (in some chart) of the differentials forms?

Comment: That depends on your starting point. How did you define the exterior derivative? If the exterior derivative was defined in terms of coordinates, you'll have to use coordinates to prove any other properties. If you have a coordinate free definition, then you may be able to give a coordinate free proof.

Comment: I have edited my question adding the definition of the exterior derivative.

Comment: Hit it with $X_1,\dots,X_{k+\ell+1}$ and just expand everything.  It is easier if you use antisymmetry.